# In Google Analytics, how can I determine the value of a page if no goals or revenue have been determined?

Tags: google-analytics

I have 4 years of data in Analytics with over 20 million pageviews for the entire site. No goals have ever been set up, and while the site is an ecommerce site, no ecommerce features in Google Analytics have ever been taken advantage of. So I have no way to determine what the actual value of a page is.

I've been tasked with determining if a particular page on the site is worth keeping around. How might I use all standard data (pageviews, bounce rate, time on page, time on site, etc.) to help determine the value of this page?

I really appreciate any help I can get!

Comment: A few questions to help clarify. 1. Is the page a product specific page or a non-commerce page that you think might have an influence on commerce pages? 2. Do you have access to other data such as sales or how many widgets have been sold? (You might be able to get it from the website itself).

Comment: Hi @Joshak — 1. It's essentially a list of all products. 2. I do not, unfortunately. I need to base it on other, out-of-the-box stats in GA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the additional information you provided I'd say look at entrances to that page. I'm guessing the purpose of this page is to drive traffic to the individual product pages. If lots of people are entering the site on that page (and not bouncing) then presumably your product pages are getting lots of traffic they would not otherwise get.

The in page analytics may also help determine it it's really sending traffic to your products or if it's sending traffic elsewhere.

There are exceptions to this of course. For example if most of the entrances are coming from paid search you may be better off picking more targeted landing pages for your ads.

Other additional considerations might be the number of external links pointing to that page, from an SEO perspective hub pages such as that could be leveraged to get your best product pages ranked well for money keywords. You'd want good content beyond just product listings to make this work but it could be worth it.